# How to calculate mean color of image in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have an RGB image that has been converted to a numpy array.  I'm trying to calculate the average RGB value of the image using numpy or scipy functions.

The RGB values are represented as a floating point from 0.0 - 1.0, where 1.0 = 255.

A sample 2x2 pixel image_array:

```
[[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]]
```

I have tried:

```
import numpy
numpy.mean(image_array, axis=0)`
```

But that outputs:

```
[[0.5  0.5  0.5]
 [0.5  0.5  0.5]]
```

What I want is just the single RGB average value:

```
[0.5  0.5  0.5]
```

Answer (score 47):

You're taking the mean along only one axis, whereas you need to take the mean along two axes: the height and the width of the image.

Try this:

```
>>> image_array    
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])
>>> np.mean(image_array, axis=(0, 1))
array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5])
```

As the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html#numpy.mean) will tell you, you can specify a tuple for the `axis` parameter, specifying the axes over which you want the mean to be taken.

Comment: Thats it!  I didn't realize you could specify more than one axis.